# Setting a signature of a task as starting task of multipe chain in celery

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery, celery-task, celery-canvas

Suppose A to G are async tasks and we want to implement a task workflow like this canvas

```
     /---> B()
A()  ----> C() -> D()
     \---> E() -> F() -> G()
```

According to the problem, we need to use the result of A() for starting of multiple chains.

In code:

```
from celery import chain

# A (params) ?????

B.apply_async(params)
chain(
    C.s(params), D.s(params)
).apply_async()
chain(
    E.s(params), F.s(params), G.s(params)
).apply_async()
```

In the Celery Canvas, how can I use the result of A() to first elements of multiple chains asynchronously without run the A() three times?

(I'm using the Celery 4.1.0 and RabbitMQ as a broker)

Comment: if `a=A.apply_async(params)` etc, did you try to `(a | group(b, (c | d), (e | f | g))` ?

Comment: @ItayB Thanks, I need something like your comment. The result of `a` function will pass to `b` but how can I pass the result of `a` to `c` and `e`?

Comment: actually I never tried this scenario, are you sure that it wont? did u try? in theory, because it's a group `c` can start before `b` and also `e`, are you sure that only the first one in the `group` gets the previous result?

Comment: @ItayB I know! `b`, `c`, `e` not preserve order but surely `a` will done before all of them because there is a chain. I just want to use the return value of `a` as input parameters of `b`, `c` and `e`.

Comment: @ItayB Please write your solution (`(a | group(b, (c | d), (e | f | g))`) as an answer :)

Comment: I'm not sure it is, I'll have to test it first. I can suggest workaround if you like..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know! `b`, `c`, `e` not preserve order but surely `a` will done before all of them because there is a chain. I just want to use the return value of `a` as input parameters of `b`, `c` and `e`.